# Control 8V H-Bridge with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, h-bridge

Good afternoon.

I've been trying to control an 8V H-Bridge (PMOS+NMOS) with a 4V microcontroller output signal. I thouth it would work but then i read that the PMOS source voltage had to be equal or smaller than the control voltage in the PMOS/NMOS gates. Does somebody know how to deal with this problem (without adding much more electronics)?

[image]

Comment: In addition to needing a "level shifter" for the PMOS gate signal, beware of connecting the gates together in this fashion. There is likely a significant difference between the threshold voltages of the two MOSFETs. During the transition between the two, both MOSFETs will be on causing a short-circuit during the transition time. It is common to drive these separately with a "dead band" which guarantees that one MOSFET is off before the other turns on.

Comment: "There is likely a significant difference between the threshold voltages of the two MOSFETs" ... I am referring to the threshold voltages relative to DC common in your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't drive the PMOS transistor directly like that. Remember that the gate voltage is always referenced to the source terminal, so if you apply 8V to the source and 0-4V to the gate, the gate-source voltage varies between -8V and -4V. In other words, the PMOS can never shut off, because it's gats-source voltage never goes to zero.

To fix this, you need to create a "level shifter" for the PMOS gate signal. There are many ways to do this; one of the easiest is to purchase a driver chip designed specifically for the task.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to PWM very fast you can simply use a low-to-high logic level converter from the 4000 family (eg. [CD40109B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40109b.pdf)). Drive current is only a few mA so they'll not drive big MOSFETs fast.

There are plenty of gate-driver chips if you need to drive a big MOSFET fast (hundreds of mA or amperes of current drive to supply the gate charge fast), but they tend to be more expensive.